# Which account I should use for defining “Service Account” for SharePoint products and sql server reporting during my TFS instalation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation, tfs

I have installed the following:-

- SharePoint server 2013.
- Visual studio professional 2012
- Sql server 2008 r2 sp2

And currently I am installing visual studio team foundation server 2012, but during the installation I was asked to provide an account name to be used as a service account for SharePoint products, so I have the following questions:-

1. Should this user already exists?.
2. I have already define a service account while installing the sql server, so should/can I use this account?
   Thnak

Comment: Your SP service account needs to be a local admin on the machine you're installing SP to.

Here's a brief overview of suggested user accounts - it's for SP2013 but the ideas are similar enough across SP2007/2010/2013:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14500.sharepoint-2013-best-practices-service-accounts.aspx

Comment: so for team foundation server i can use the sql_service user which i already have to define the "Service Account" for TFS?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't in case you end up using the database for multiple applications. But if you're running the server as an all-in-one appliance there's nothing stopping you doing so. I'm always of the mindset 'one account per application' and SP spawns *a lot* of databases so at least if it does so with a unique username it might make for easier problem solving/cleaning later on.